# How can we display permissions to users?

Tags: 7, views, users

Is there any way we can display user permissions (e.g. *delete all nodes*) to a user role inside a view?

Permissions would be change-able with check-boxes.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, I want those permissions to be change-able.

Comment: `Permissions would be change-able with check-boxes.`? Hopefully this view is for admins only... you don't want any user to change permissions.

Comment: yes of course. This view is only for admins.

Comment: I thought of simply displaying `admin/people/permissions` to admin but then if there is any better solutions. Also if possible, I wanna display only few of all permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a view of permissions you'd have to write a custom module that would allow views to do the search. I'm not aware of a module that does that now. Given how roles are defined and managed this would be a challenging module to get right.

If you just want to improve the user interface for permissions form you might look at these modules:

- [filter permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms)
- [Permission Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/permission_select)
- [Fast Permissions Administration](https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa)

If you want to give admins a limited number of roles they can assign the [Role Assign module](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleassign) may provide what you need.